# How to edit excel file as a template and let the client download it in ExcelJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, excel, file, exceljs

I am using React and ExcelJS.

I have 1 excel file that I want to use it as a template for the clients to download a modified version of it.

Let me explain in more detail. I will have this excel file in the server where the path is known. In the website, I will have a button that will do the following:

1. Use the template file (be it copy to modify or any other ways)
2. Edit the file (by adding data into cells)
3. Save the file if necessary (if it creates a new file, I want it to be temporary)
4. Let the client download the file via the browser (as an excel file)

How to achieve such task?

ps. I am not using NodeJS.

Comment: you have t do the job on the server using a backend solution (nodejs or golang etc.)